# What is special on adding .00 after the divide function at sql

Tags: sql, division

I know it is a simple question. But can someone tell me why the result of year/100 is different from year/100.00?

year/100 results in a >1 value 
but 
year/100.00 results in a <0 with decimal value

**For example:**

Table: Year

Column:

```
    year(1601)

    year(2000)
```

Expected result is to return

```
   (17)
   (20)
```

The calculation is if the variable divided by 100 and the remaining is more than 0, then round up and add 1 to it. If after division and the remaining is 0, then keep the integer.

```
   year    yr1         yr2
   1601   0.1601E2      16
   2000   0.2E2         20
```

**Here's the code I used to calculate yr1 and yr2**
yr1: year/100.00
yr2: year/100

Can someone help explaining the different of using '100' or '100.00'?

Thank you

Comment: well, if you add .00, this means you are trying to cast it as decimal instead of integer.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the arithmetic operations result in same datatype as the datatype of operands. So integer / integer yields an integer thus 1601 / 100 = 16.

If the operands are different datatypes then the operand with lower datatype precedence is converted to the datatype of the other operand. In your example, 1601 is an integer and 100.00 is a *decimal literal* representing `decimal(5,2)`. So integer is first converted to a decmial for division and the result of 1601 / 100.00 = 16.010000; where the result is of type `decimal(12, 6)`. You can even use `100.0` or `100.` literal to get same result.

See [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [precision/scale calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more detail.